# Assistance with differentiating URLs and Tableview Data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Disclaimer, new to this: I am developing an app that provides different resources for each item within a TableView. When the user makes a selection, the app segues into a new ViewController. While the viewController is the same for each TableView selection, the URL Buttons within should have different URLs respective to the tableview selection.

I'm having issues with being able to code different URLS to each tableView array [Week 0 thru Week 8]. Right now, the buttons within View Controller have the same URLS for each tableview selection. Hopefully I explained clearly enough, but code is attached. Please let me know if anymore information is required. Thank you!

```
import UIKit

class WeekTableViewController: UITableViewController {



    var week = [
    "Week 0:",
    "Week 1:",
    "Week 2:",
    "Week 3:",
    "Weel 4:",
    "Week 5:",
    "Week 6:",
    "Week 7:",
    "Week 8:"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }





    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return week.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedWeek = week[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier:"moveToWeekDetail", sender:selectedWeek)
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = week[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if let weekViewController = segue.destination as? WeekDetailViewController{
            if let selectedWeek = sender as? String{
                weekViewController.title = selectedWeek
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the week's description from a simple String to a struct:

```
/// A struct to hold information about each week
/// Add more properties as needed
struct WeekInfo {
    let description: String
    let url: URL
}

class WeekTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    // It's no longer an array of strings
    var week = [
        WeekInfo(description: "Week 1", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
        WeekInfo(description: "Week 2", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
        WeekInfo(description: "Week 3", url: URL(string: "https://somewhere.com")!),
    ]

    // ...

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
        if let weekViewController = segue.destination as? WeekDetailViewController{
            // Pass the week's info onto the detail view controller
            if let selectedWeek = sender as? WeekInfo {
                weekViewController.title = selectedWeek.description
                weekViewController.week = selectedWeek
            }
        }
    }
}

class WeekDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    // Info about the week
    var week: WeekInfo!
}
```